# Applescript-based Droplet does not take all files dropped on

Tags: applescript, droplet

We have an utility to process images, built as a standard Applescript droplet (using the code floating around with distinction between folders and individual files).

On one installation (MacBook Pro, macOS 11.5), dragging on a single folder works fine, but when dragging on a selection of 4 files, only 2 get processed. An alert at the beginning of the code confirms that only two files are "taken". Various tests by exclusion show that we have a set of 2 specific files which make the other 2 not being processed. If in the group we drag onto the droplet, one of those files is included, only that one gets taken.

On other installations (iMac, macOS 11.5 or virtual macOS 10.14), this effect does not show up with the same files.

Has anyone heard of such an effect? What can be the cause? What can be done to avoid it?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: _Exactly_ what/where are the files causing the problem?  Can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I also asked the question on the Latenight Software forum (the makers of Script Debugger, which I used to create the droplet. There, I got the hint to the Quarantaine flag, which was the key to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, it seems to be a timing issue when feeding the files into the droplet, caused by the Quarantaine flag.

This keword lead to https://superuser.com/questions/1336044/how-to-clear-remove-macos-extended-attributes-recursively-from-a-directory on how to display and remove that flag. After removing it, all files processed properly.

What I will have to do now, is build a little utility which allows to strip that flag, as the issue happens when feeding the droplet.